# Windows user folder size less than actual size

Tags: window

I have a question about Windows user folder size.

I'm using Windows 10 latest version, let's denote my pc user name as `abc`. When I right click the folder `c:\users\abc` and select *Properties*, Windows tells me the size of this folder is 16.7 GB.

But when I open this folder `c:\users\abc`, select all sub-folders, like `documents`, `downloads`, ... again right click to see properties, Windows now tells me the size is 49.2 GB, which is the actual size.

I didn't create any symlinks nor hidden files here. So why there is so huge the difference? BTW, this only happens to my user folder `c:\users\abc`, other directories seem pretty fine with size display.

Edit 1: I'm not asking how to get or visualize the correct folder size. My question is why the two displayed sizes are so different? Also, in my case, it's the folder size 'much less' than the actual size, not 'more' than, nor 'slightly different from'.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/524134/windows-7-disk-properties-dialog-reports-more-used-space-than-total-size-of-file

Comment: @music2myear thank you for the information, but they were talking about some a small difference due to some NTFS features, but in my case the difference is so big so I don't think it's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed as a bug in Windows 10 version 1803, no solution yet.

> Enumerating a folder’s content in explorer just returns wrong data. A
>   2TB-HD contains e.g. real 43.048 files, 4.123 files and occupies 735
>   GB. Listing the folder properties in Windows 1803 will display: 4,104
>   files, 2,113 folders an a size of 98.9 GB. Only if the user go to the
>   folder, select all files (and subfolders) with CTRL+A, then the
>   properties are calculated correctly (in this case).

Ref: https://borncity.com/win/2018/05/04/windows-10-april-update-bugs-and-issues/

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful to the community in my opinion.  We often find that when links stop working, answers that contained only a link, almost become unhelpful and/or incomplete.

Comment: I would find this answer to be more persuasive if it linked to a more authoritative or even reputable source. The site referenced above looks like a personal blog, and has many typos.