# Different used size for the same partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

I have drives C and D on my computer. Drive C is for the Windows and system files. I tried to backup my files on drive D. But I found that the used size of this partition is not consistent. For example, when I R-Click on the partition, then properties, I can see the used size as 34 GB. However, when I open the same partition and select all files, then R-Click, and properties, I can see the used size as 8 GB.

What is the reason for this difference?

Notes:
1- I have Windows 7 on my computer.
2- I don't have any hidden files.
3- I run the disk clean up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you defragmented your hard disk recently? You "*don't have any hidden files*", but the system does, and it also has 'system' files that you probably can't see and thus didn't select.

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: @Attie No, I have never defragmented my hard disk.

Comment: Using properties on your system disk is an inefficient way of finding out much space your using.  Using something like, WinDirStat, and run it as an Administrator to get an accurate picture of your disk usage.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure these are system files, e.g restore points or volume shadow copies. As other guys mentioned before, you can check that with WinDirStart for example.

Here's another thread about this: [Why don't the sizes of my folders add up to the size of my hard drive in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows).

Comment: The question is why such a huge difference? 8 to 34? it is nearly four times! In addition, as you can see from the third photo, I have unticked everything to make everything visible. Based on others suggestion, I used WinDirStat, and I found it measures 8.18GB.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt as administrator and run these commands

```
> D:
> attrib *.* -R -A -S -H -O -I -X /S /L
```

This command should show any hidden file in root of D: partition .

You can also use a free drive scanning utility - [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) . It helps you to visualize which folders and files are taking up all of the space on your hard drive .