# Why isn't the directory size the same as the sum of its children for Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, filesystems

I have a directory that contains a ton of music that it showing weird file sizes in Windows 10. When I click on the directory containing all the music, it shows 809GB and over 164k files. When I select all the folders and files within that directory to check the sum of their size, it shows only 9.14GB and 2k files. The difference here is staggering.

Though this question is very similar to [https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows#*=*](https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows#_=_) it differs in the fact that I am sure I have selected all hidden files, and I double checked the filesize on Linux which confirms that the real filesize of the Music directory is around 9.14GB.  I attempted to do the `cleanmgr` but no change was made to the parent directory's size

[image]
Note that the `Old Music` directory in `C:\Sorted Drive\Music\Old Music` is 809 yet all of the files in `C:\Sorted Drive\Music\Old Music\Old Music` is only 9.14GB

Update:
I've change some folder settings to see if some extra hidden system files weren't showing up when selecting all sub directories and files but there was no change.

I've moved the files to different folders and found that the filesize of the parent directory changes to some random value. Even changing the name of the parent directory can change the filesize

Comment: tried [ View > Options > View Tab :  Tick -> "Show hidden files. folders and drives" & Untick these : "Hide empty dives ", "Hide extensions for known file types ", "Hide folder merge conflicts", "Hide protected operating system files " ] ?

Comment: Why are you comparing `F:\Sorted Drive\Music\Old Music` with  `F:\Sorted Drive\Music\Old Music\Old Music` ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ I have show hidden files checked along with showing the file extensions. I’ll try unticking some of the other things you suggested. Wouldn’t those be counted in when checking the disk usage for the folder though?

Comment: @harrymc the left image is checking “Old Music” in “C:\Sorted Drive\Music\Old Music” while the right image is checking all the folders in “..\Old Music\Old Music”

Comment: In regard of total disk space, does the number of 809GB seem correct?

Comment: When checking the disk usage on the C drive on windows, it appears that it is calculating in the 809GB, but when checking on Linux, it is not taking that it is not reflecting that and seems way more in line with the 9GB figure

Comment: IMHO.. for "Wouldn’t those be counted in..." I've seen cases where it did happens that way to me.. but I'm not using Win10 during that time.. ( : || Do you get the same folder properties as posted here after the operation? if yes.. it should make sense now. If no (the same properties rendered..) then my move normally is just to move the folders around (to some test folder) to cut the (fileSize) cake.. and make sense of it.

Comment: @p._phidot_ I made the changes you suggested but there has been no change to the file sizes. Selecting all files within `..\Old Music\Old Music` still shows 9.14GB

Comment: I tried moving files to different locations. I created a `C:\test\` folder, eventually moved all files and folders from `../Old Music/Old  Music/` to that folder, read the file size of the `test` folder.. It showed 9.14GB, I read the size of `Old dock` 0 bytes...  I moved all files back to the original folder, back up to 809GB

Comment: I noticed that there were a lot of recurring `Old Music` folders (All containing different music), and wanted to remove/rename them wondering if Windows 10 glitches out and has some weird recursion errors or something. I moved all the music into the `C:\Sorted drive\Music\Old Music\` folder and checked the file size. It's now reporting around 3GB when I check on the folder, still 9.14GB with the entire contents. Perhaps my windows install is borked somehow, I'd imagine other people would notice such weird issues by now.

Comment: Just curious.. what is the size of that "New Music" folder ? (in your screenshot. )

Comment: "New Music" is 3.41GB (The 3GB figure above is Closer to 3.15GB)

Comment: I've actually noticed that several directories have incorrect sizes and the sizes change for no good reason (Renaming folders changes the sizes considerably) Luckily, I've found that these phantom sizes aren't effecting how much disk space my C drive has noticeably (I made a claim that close to 1TB of space was taken which is much too high is wrong, a few games I had downloaded were considerably larger than I expected)

Anyway, I am willing to try more things to get to the bottom of this, but I am considering that my Windows10 install is just wonky

Comment: Do you have File History enabled on either of these directories?  I suggest using a program like WInDirStat or WizTree to determine the actual size of the directory provided you enable unknown files (i.e. Shadow Volume).