# Windows 10 doesn't calculate used space on disk properly

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, disk-space, storage-spaces

I am attaching screenshot of the problem 
[Disk size comparasion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rhDq.jpg)

When I select everything in C:\ it calculates different size of when I see my C: drive in "This PC".

I am trying to understand what is using that much storage but I can't find anything.

I am using SSD. I check with chkdsk for Bad Sectors but there aren't any.

I am new here so if the information is not enough please just tell me I will try to explain it better. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate...https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the sizes of my folders add up to the size of my hard drive in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include "hidden files," Windows continues to exclude a subset of hidden files called "protected operating system files," unless this default behavior is also explicitly disabled.

Including hidden files in your total will definitely reduce the discrepancy you currently see between the two storage-usage totals.

There are some potentially massive files in the root of your C drive that aren't being included right now:

- pagefile.sys
- swapfile.sys
- hiberfil.sys

[image]

However, even with both hidden and protected operating system files included in the total, the sum of the individual files and folders may still fall short of the total amount of space reported by Windows for the entire C drive.

If this happens and you still want to find out exactly where your missing gigabytes went, install [TreeSize](https://customers.jam-software.de/downloadTrial.php?article_no=80) by JAM Software. This free utility indexes your files and folders in seconds and will show you how Windows reaches that 155 GB total.

Comment: I found out there is a bug in the Version of Windows I used (1803). After I updated Windows to the last version the issue has dissapeared. 

@wrecclesham I have one question about TreeSize. Is the software safe? Since it scan all folders and files on your computer.

Comment: @xezzy yeah it's 100% safe. The first version came out in 2007, so it's been around for a long time now. It's widely regarded as the best tool of its kind for Windows.

Comment: Thank you very much!